# Two xwin-xdg-menu processes with high CPU consumption

Tags: cygwin, x11

I have a Windows 7 computer with intel i7 with 2 cores and hyperthreading and a linux virtual machine in a cloud. I don't like VNC (it's laggy) so I use X windowing.

I start my Cygwin XWin with the following command:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; /usr/bin/xinit /etc/X11/xinit/startxwinrc -- /usr/bin/XWin :0 -multiwindow -listen tcp"
```

It's working otherwise just as intended but for some reason it's spawning two xwin-xdg-menu processes of which the other one is consuming 25% of my CPU. When I kill it, the CPU usage returns to normal and everything is working fine, including the other xwin-xdg-menu process.

I tried also this:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\XWin.exe :0 -multiwindow -listen tcp
```

but it makes the application run slowly and with a bad resolution.

Is there a way to start X with listen-tcp with an adapted resolution to my multiple screens I have and without having to manually kill the extra process every time?

It seems I'm not the only one with this problem but for now I haven't found any solution to this.
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2017-05/msg00345.html
https://superuser.com/questions/1210325/cygwin-at-spi-bus-launcher-and-xwin-xdg-menu-high-cpu (I don't have problems with at-spi-bus-launcher though)

Comment: you should use startxwin and not xinit

Comment: At least swapping xinit to startxwin didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**
Create a **~/.startxwinrc** file, and add one line:

```
exec sleep infinity
```

Make ~/.startxwinrc executable by running `chmod +x ~/.startxwinrc`.

**Reason I suspect this worked:**
[startxwin](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/startxwin.1.html) searches for a ~/.startxwinrc file to execute when launching.  If startxwin does not find a ~/.startxwinrc file, startxwin will follow the default routine outlined in `/etc/X11/xinit/startxwinrc`.

The default routine launches /usr/bin/xwin-xdg-menu, somehow causing me to have two xwin-xdg-menu processes, one of them with very high cpu. Creating ~/.startxwinrc bypasses the default routine, disabling /usr/bin/xwin-xdg-menu from launching altogether.

[exec sleep infinity](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-startxwinrc-exit) keeps the x server alive after launching.

Comment: This solution will remove one of the Windows task bar icons from where you can start some apps, but I can live with that. It should also be possible to copy the contents in /etc/...  and optimize it for your own need.